# Don't apply existing migrations for a Django model

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-1.10

I need to tell Django not to apply *already existing* migrations for a model. Is there a way I can achieve it?

Why: I have some customizations on top of `django.contrib.auth`. With those, `Group` model is left unused. However, migrations for it are included into the auth app. Unlike `User`, `Group` is not `swappable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set [`MIGRATION_MODULES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#migration-modules) and django will use migrations from setted directory for app

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {'django.contrib.auth': 'local_package'}
```

Comment: Great, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply edit the migrations files. 
So, simply comment out the parts you don't want to be applied.

You can also set your Model to be `managed=False` , but I'm not sure if that is what you need.

Comment: Editing migrations could be an option, would they belong to me. But they are in ```django.contrib.auth```, and I don't feel like having my own repository with a django branch because of it :( ```managed=False``` in ```Meta``` prevents migrations from being created.

Comment: i dont see the problem. Please describe more clearly what you have and what you want.

Comment: The problem is this: https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/auth/migrations Those migrations are shipped with Django. When I need to deploy my projects on production, I install Django from pip.